# MISSING FUNDS ON BLOCKCHAIN

Tags: blockchain.info

Please help me out. i have never shared my wallet ID or password with anyone. i only loss access to my blockchain account because i misplaced my phone and i had to reset my 2FA. It has been approved and then i logged into my account yesterday. To my greatest suprise it was empty. I have some amount of bitcoins and i could not find any of it and there are also no transaction history anymore please help me out With any suggestions of what might have happened.my school fees i had it all there. something is clearly wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MISSING FUNDS AT BLOCKCHAIN](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96883/missing-funds-at-blockchain)

Answer (score 1):

The moment you disabled 2FA, you removed an important level of security for your account.
If your funds have been moved and it wasn't you, most likely someone entered your account and robbed you.

First, I advise you to use a **real** Bitcoin wallet, not blockchain.com/info.
Second, you should check [this page](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/210929703-Advanced-Security-) and enable a couple of advanced security options.

Comment: The problem is that I never shared my details with anyone and also there is no transaction history appearing at all.  That’s why I don’t understand what happened.

Comment: If there's no transaction history showing the bitcoins moved, they probably haven't moved at all and are still there.